# Interdependent frameworks Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm working on a set of (internal use only) frameworks that encapsulate various elements of my development process.  Some of these frameworks are dependent on one another, but I'd like to keep them separate so as to be more manageable.  I'm running into various compiler errors now which I *think* have to do with the dependencies overlapping.

At the moment all of these frameworks and an app share the same workspace as different projects. How can I configure my app and frameworks to compile in this situation?

Here's the boiled down idea:

**App dependencies:** A.framework B.framework C.framework D.framework

**A.framework dependencies** none

**B.framework dependencies**  A.framework

**C.framework dependencies**  A.framework B.framework

**D.framework dependencies**  none

**More info:**

Currently, in C.framework, I have dragged A and B.frameworks into the "Frameworks" folder.  I read elsewhere to do that an to *not* Link Binary With Libraries.  Either way, I get a compiler error for some functions that are in the headers of both A and B.framework:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

The build settings for A & B have "Build Active Architectures Only" set to NO and valid architectures set to include "armv7".

B.framework, however has no issue building.

**Update :**

I'm now able to get the App to build, by Linking Binaries in each of the targets... however it immediately crashed with this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/A.framework/A
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/94488FD7-B731-4E6B-86E6-3D2F09BB4E04/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Update your question with sample errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I seem to have gotten past this in the following way.

Instead of having my workspace have each framework as a separate "top-level" project, I moved the framework projects into sub projects of the App project.

Then, I added each framework to the App's "Embed Frameworks" section (and was able to remove it from "Link Binary.." and "Target Dependencies" sections.

Within each framework, I used the "Link Binary..." section to include the dependent frameworks.

I'm not sure that I understand all the pieces to why this works, but at least I can move on!

Thanks @vel-genov for your help!

Comment: If this is a final solution that worked for you, please accept your own answer so it will be clear to others that this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely causing this error message is related to the libraries not building in the correct order.

One possible solution to the order the libraries get built lies in adding all dependent libraries as sub-projects to the main project. This is appropriate when all projects are owned and maintained by the same entity, as the OP mentioned.

Add each project to the main one by going to "Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.", then add each framework project file using the "+" button. Then go to each sub-project, and add it's dependencies.

For **B.framework** project, go to "Link Binary With Libraries.", and add **A.framework** as a dependency.

Similarly, for **C.framework**, add **A.framework** and **B.framework**, as dependencies.

As a suggestion, also add all frameworks to "Link Binary With Libraries.", under the main project, all of them get used.

One thing to keep an eye out in such situation, is to make sure there are no circular dependencies, and dependencies don't get added multiple times in different projects.

The image below shows an example of a similar setup to the one in the OP. There is a **FrameworkTest** project. All 4 frameworks are added as "Link Binary With Libraries." under it. For **FrameworkB**, **FrameworkA** is added under "Link Binary With Libraries.". Similarly workflow for **FrameworkC**. Xcode seemed to figure out the dependencies without the need for "Target Dependancies" settings. This project builds and runs. Haven't gotten as far as calling items from each framework.

[image: Screenshot of a sample project]

Another solution to this, using a workspace would be to have one top level project, and move each framework as a sub-project. Then add each framework to the top-level project's "Embedded Frameworks" section.

Use the "Link Binary With Libraries." section of each framework sub-project, to define its dependencies.

Comment: thanks.  unfortunately it's not letting me add anything to the "Target Dependencies" section.

Comment: Once you go through the "Link Binary with Libraries" step, the newly linked library will show up under the "Target Dependancies" section. "The dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/A.framework/A," error message could be the result of that particular library not getting built.

Comment: @olynoise, put together a sample project. Take a look and let me know how that works for you.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it -- thanks for the picture, that got me on the right track, as I had each framework as a "top-level" project in the workspace.  Moving them into the App project allowed me to use "Embed Frameworks" to bring the projects in.. Not sure exactly what's going on, but at least it works now!

Comment: Glad that worked for you @olynoise. I'll incorporate the workflow into my answer, if you don't mind. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these settings are correct:

1. FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS (in Build Settings)
2. Link Binary With Libraries (in Build Phases)
3. INSTALL_PATH (change to `@rpath` for all frameworks) (in Build Phases)
4. `@rpath` (Runpath Search Paths) (add `@executable_path/../Frameworks` for your app and all frameworks that need embedded another framework) (in Build Settings)