# How to make umbrella framework, sub-framework error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

How to make umbrella framework in xcode 8? I saw this 
[How to create an umbrella framework in iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk) and [How to add a framework inside another framework (Umbrella Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681435/how-to-add-a-framework-inside-another-framework-umbrella-framework/34837164#34837164), but i cant make 'Umbrella framework'. 
Unfortunately when adding the umbrella framework into another project I get various "undefined symbol" errors from the sub-frameworks. How to include sub-framework into umbrella, i want to add only umbrella in app, not sub-framework. Please someone help me with this.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you that apple don't suggest to make umbrella framework. So don't make it!

Comment: You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34776343/3840908

Comment: I read about that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged, but i need to make umbrella, both framework are mine, and it will be easier for distribution.

Comment: Refer this here it is updated for XCode 8 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34837164/3840908

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a framework inside another framework (Umbrella Framework)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681435/how-to-add-a-framework-inside-another-framework-umbrella-framework)

Comment: @iYoung i refer to these links in question. That answers don't help me.